# Angular Material: I am adding one more row of matInput in Angular form on button click. but matInput filed UI is not loading properly

Tags: angular, angular-material

I am adding one more row of matInput in Angular form on button click if the user wants to insert one more record. but matInput filed UI is not loading properly. it's getting load when I do focus in and focus out.
**I also tried changeDetectionref but no luck.**
  I am adding one more row with this code

```
      createItem() {
    return this.fb.group({
      'attribute_name': ["", Validators.required],
      'attribute_XPath': ["", Validators.required]
    })
  }
const items = this.regiForm.controls.formgrp as FormArray;
items['controls'].push(this.createItem());
```

Here is the UI you can see in the third row of matInput's CSS is missing. 
it's coming on blur.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because the change detection is not recognizing the added items. Change detection is triggered when the object reference changes, but is not triggered if a property within the object changes.

You can manually trigger a change detection by adding the `private cdr: ChangeDetectorRef` to your class constructor and calling `this.cdr.detectChanges();` at the end of your function.

Comment: Unfortunately it is hard to tell with the small amount of code you posted. You could try putting the last line inside of a `setTimeout()`. That function and `setInterval()` were monkey patched to trigger change detection updates in angular.